# Call ViewController's object from subclass

Tags: ipad, ios6, uiviewcontroller, subclass

I'm developing an iOS 6 app for iPad. I have a Subclass and I'd like to call a ViewController's object from it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to access the properties of your ViewController into your subclass. then treat that properties is like your subclass properties.

subclass means you have derived base viewController into your subviewController i.e. now you have all properties & methods of baseViewController into your subViewController.

example- it is like you are inheriting TableViewController into ViewController

```
@interface ViewController: UITableViewController
```

now here you can easily use tableView of TableViewController as like it is the property of your ViewController & you can access it like

```
self.tableView
```

Comment: But the problem is that it's not a subclass of the ViewController, it's a UIScrolView subclass. So it doesn't work.

Comment: it's just like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044677/modifying-uibuttons-alpha-property-not-working-ios